# Why we use local ip address in ip spoofing?

Tags: python, networking, ip, scapy, spoofing

As you can see local ip address used here.But for example we do ip spoofing so that the spesific website
cant see our ip address.Then we need to type our public address.

The question i try to ask is why we're not using public ip address instead local ip address ?
Here is my example code :

```
from scapy.all import * 

A = '192.168.0.101'
B = '192.168.0.102'
C = 10000
D = 20000
payload = "yada yada yada"

spoofed_packet = IP(src=A,dst=B) / TCP(sport=C,dport=D) / payload

send(spoofed_packet)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Local IP" addresses as defined in RFC 1918 are *non routable* addresses.  This means that a router in the internet should discard them.  Otherwise, these routers would route the responses to these packets back to the specified public IP addresses.

If you were to specify public IP addresses, it would result in the responses being sent back to those public IP addresses which could be viewed as a form of network abuse.

Comment: How does this answer the question of why local IP addresses are used in IP spoofing? I'm not saying the question is coherent, but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i still didnt understand and  there is a question too in my mind.Local address are for local networks and publics are for international connections.So for example if i spoof my ip address for any website, that website can't see my ip address right ?